# Troubles with Jquery responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my responsive menu I'v got some trouble with:

[image: responsive menu]

But when it toggles down, it close the main content area. I need something like this:

When the menu is toggled down, the main content area toggles down with the menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#burg").click(function(){

        $("#slideul").toggle("slow");

    });

});
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML / CSS thats goes alongside the JS :)

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning for your menu.

Comment: If you want  that your site be responsive, don't use position, margin or padding, use the flexbox with display: flex; and flex: valor; Only that without prefix isn't supported at 100% with all browser

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your menu relatively positioned to the rest of your content.

Ensure that the HTML for your menu appears first in the DOM and when your menu expands it will push down the rest of the content.

Simply remove

```
position: absolute
```

from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It wold be better to post your code but i think you should give a `position: relative` to you whole navigation element.